# Custom post type / Filter by letter

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

So I've created a custom post type called "Profiles" for a school website I'm working on. Purpose of this content type is to list all teachers with their names, profile picture, bio, etc.

Right now, the content is being display using a custom archive and I would like to know if there's a way to add filters to this post type so users can sort the profiles by letter...

For example, it would be cool to have letters from A to Z listed and then if the user clicks on the "A" link, list all profiles inside the letter A.

Is there a way to accomplish this on Wordpress. I've search for plugins without luck.

Thanks!

Johann

Comment: There's always a way to accomplish something: It's to write it. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a query result, ordered by your titles `ASC` and wrapped each "block" in a div with the `id="A"`, etc.:

There's a PHP function to fill arrays:

```
$aToZ = range( 'A', 'Z' );
```

Then you can loop through it:

```
echo '<ul class="aToZ-list">';
foreach ( $aToZ as $char )
    echo "<li class="aToZ-el"><a href='#{$char}' title='Go to {$char}'>{$char}</a></li>";
echo '</ul>';
```

Now you have a list that you can style via CSS.